# Is there a Javascript global functions to namespace ones (Number.*) list?

Tags: javascript

`parseFloat` is a global function and it seems that ECMA5/6 tends to remove the global things from their spec, hence adding a `Number.parseFloat` method that behave the same ( see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat )

But is there a list of all functions that went throught that process?

I can see, from MDN `Number`'s page, that global functions `isFinite isInteger isNaN isSafeInteger parseFloat parseInt` can now be replaced by their `Number.*` equivalent, but what about `decodeURI` or `eval` or `escape` (or [any other global function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_global.asp) ) ?

Comment: *"...and it seems that ECMA5/6 tends to remove the global things from their spec..."* No, the global ones are not removed (nor will they ever be). JavaScript's steering body (TC39) takes backward-compatibility **very** seriously.

Answer (score 1):

> But is there a list of all functions that went throught that process?

There's [the specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/). You can find the default globals [here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-global-object), and see which ones are also now properties of various built-ins. I think it's just `parseInt` (`Number.parseInt`) and `parseFloat` (`Number.parseFloat`) that are **exactly** the same. [`isNaN`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-isnan-number) and [`Number.isNaN`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-number.isnan) are slightly different (the latter doesn't do a convert-to-number step first, it just immediately returns false if the input isn't a number). [`isFinite`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-isfinite-number) and [`Number.isFinite`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-number.isfinite) have the same difference. I don't think any of the other default global functions (`eval`, `decodeURI`, `decodeURIComponent`, `encodeURI`, `encodeURIComponent`) have identical or similar functions on a built-in.